# Why is my variable not initializing?

Tags: c++, initialization

I'm just moving from c to C++ and am trying to build a calculator. Int 'result' does not get initialized with the maths operations. The logic is that depending on the operation 's' there will be a different value assigned to 'result'. This does not seem to work.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int n1, n2;
    char s,r;
    int result = 0;
    cout<< "Enter a calculation? (y/n)"<<endl;
    cin>>r;
    while(r=='y')
    {
        cout <<"Enter the first number"<<endl;
        cin>>n1;
        cout<<"Enter the operator"<<endl;
        cin>>s;
        cout<<"Enter the second number"<<endl;
        cin>>n2;

        if ('s' == '*')
        {
            result = n1*n2;
        }
        if ('s' =='+')
        {
            result = n1+n2;
        }

        if ('s' =='-')
        {
            result = n1-n2;
        }

        if ('s' =='/')
        {
            result = n1/n2;
        }
        cout << result<<endl;
        cout<< "Enter a calculation? (y/n)"<<endl;
        cin>>r;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you ***know*** result is not initialized?  What is your evidence?  What was your input, and what output did you expect vs. what you actually saw?

Comment: *"This does not seem to work."* Why? What's the problem?

Comment: If the two answerers have guessed right at what you mean (which they probably have), "initialized" is the wrong term. The statement `int result = 0;` **initializes** `result` to `0`. The later **assignments** are not happening.

Comment: I suggest that you learn to debug your own code. If you are using an IDE to code, you should look at its help files. Otherwise, add lost of cout statements to your code to find out what is happening.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`s` is a [variable name](https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/variables), and `'s'` (surrounded by single quotes) is a [character literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/character_literal).

This means, you must compare with the variable `s` not with `'s'`. So your code should look like

```
if (s == '*')
{
    result = n1*n2;
}
```

The code

```
 if ('s' == '*')
```

compares the character literal `s` with the character literal `*`, which is always false.

Answer (score 3):

@OlafDietsche has it right.

I would also recommend switching to a `switch-case` statement:

```
switch(s)
{
    case '*': result = n1*n2;  break;
    case '+': result = n1+n2;  break;
    case '-': result = n1-n2;  break;
    case '/': result = n1/n2;  break;
}
```